# Describe all irreducible voting systems with two outcomes

Tags: voting-theory

A situation where $n$ voters choose between two candidates can be modelized
by a $n$-uple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^n$, where $a_i$ denotes
the wish of the $i$-th voter.  So the voting system (the rule which decides
which candidate will be elected from the uple) can be described as a boolean
map $f:\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^n \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. The following assumptions 
are natural on $f$ :

(1) Symmetry : $f(1-a_1,1-a_2,\ldots,1-a_n)=1-f(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ for any uple
$a_1,\ldots,a_n$.

(2) Monotonicity : if $a_k\leq b_k$ for every $k$, then 
$f(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \leq f(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$.

If $I\subsetneq \lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n \rbrace$ is such that $f$ does not depend on the coordinates $a_j$ for $j\not\in I$, we say that $I$ is a (nontrivial) coalition ; the trivial coalition is $I=\lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n \rbrace$. When there
is no nontrivial coalition, we say that $f$ is irreducible.

The question is, what are the irreducible maps $f:\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^n \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ satisfying (1) and (2) ?
When $n$ is odd, there is an obvious solution of "choosing the candidate with the most votes". I couldn't find any other examples.

My thoughts :

This is very closely related to Arrow's theorem and similar results, of course. But everything I've found so far only dealt with voting systems with at least three outcomes.

**Update:** The question can also be expressed in "measure-theoretic" terms. Indeed, if for $A\subsetneq \lbrace 1,2,\ldots, n \rbrace$ we denote by $i_A$ the indicator uple of $A$ (i.e. the uple $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ with $u_a=1$ when $a\in A$ and $0$ otherwise) and put $\mu(A)=f(i_A)$, then for the "measure" $\mu$, (1) means that $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$ when $A\subseteq B$, and (2) means that $\mu(A^{c})=1-\mu(A)$ where $A^{c}$ denotes the complement of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generalize your majority vote idea by assigning weights to the voters such that there can never be a tie between the sums of the weights on either side (e.g. if the sum of the weights is odd).

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/9a9f353eed9adf9ed1af12b77d680df8) that finds all symmetric, monotonic, irreducible voting systems for up to $6$ voters. Up to $5$ voters, they can all be described by weight assignments, but this is not the case for $6$ voters.

For $3$ voters, majority vote is the only option.

For $4$ voters, there is also only one type of voting system, where one special voter can only be overridden by a unanimous vote of the other three, corresponding to weight vectors $(2,1,1,1)$ etc., of which there are $4$.

For $5$ voters, there are three types of voting systems in addition to majority vote.

In the first type, one special voter can only be overridden by a unanimous vote of the other four, corresponding to weight vectors $(3,1,1,1,1)$ etc., of which there are $5$.

In the second type, two voters decide if they agree, and otherwise the other three decide by majority vote, corresponding to weight vectors $(2,2,1,1,1)$ etc., of which there are $10$.

In the third type, two voters decide if they agree, else two other voters decide if they agree, else the fifth voter decides, corresponding to weight vectors $(3,3,2,2,1)$ etc., of which there are $30$.

Thus, in total there are $1+5+10+30=46$ different voting systems for $5$ voters.

For $6$ voters, there are $2284$ different voting systems, of which $1322$ with $14$ permutationally inequivalent types can be specified by weights as follows:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{weights}&\text{count}\\\hline
2,1,1,1,1,1&6\\
4,1,1,1,1,1&6\\
2,2,2,1,1,1&20\\
3,2,1,1,1,1&30\\
3,3,2,1,1,1&60\\
3,2,2,2,1,1&60\\
3,3,2,2,2,1&60\\
4,3,3,1,1,1&60\\
5,2,2,2,1,1&60\\
4,2,2,1,1,1&60\\
4,3,2,2,1,1&180\\
4,3,3,2,2,1&180\\
5,3,3,2,1,1&180\\
5,4,3,2,2,1&360
\end{array}

But there are also $962$ voting systems with $9$ permutationally inequivalent types that can't be specified by weights. Here are the minimal coalitions needed to achieve the outcome $1$ (with the coalitions extending in the vertical direction to save space, so the rows correspond to voters):

$12$ voting systems with $10$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000011111
0011100011
0101101100
1010110100
1101010001
1110001010
```

$20$ voting systems with $10$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000001111
0001110001
0110110110
1011011010
1101101100
1110000001
```

$90$ voting systems with $7$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000111
0011001
0101010
0110100
1001100
1110011
```

$90$ voting systems with $10$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000000011
0000111100
0111001101
1011010110
1101101010
1110110001
```

$90$ voting systems with $11$ minimal coalitions:

```
00000011111
00011100011
01100100101
10101001001
11010111000
11111010110
```

$120$ voting systems with $10$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000001111
0001110001
0110010010
1010111100
1101100110
1111001001
```

$180$ voting systems with $7$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000011
0001100
0110101
0111010
1010110
1101001
```

$180$ voting systems with $10$ minimal coalitions:

```
0000000111
0001111001
0110011010
1010101100
1101010100
1111100011
```

$180$ voting systems with $11$ minimal coalitions:

```
00000001111
00001110001
01110010011
10110100101
11011011100
11101101010
```

Comment: Nice! All those first results look promising indeed.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Unfortunately the results for $6$ voters are more complicated. I don't see how to describe them more systematically. You might want to take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731791) (though it doesn't have any answers yet).

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely other irreducible functions that satisfy the monotonicity and symmetry conditions; here is one example. (The numbers $F_k$ below are the Fibonacci numbers.)

Take $n=7$, and let voter $k$ have $F_k$ votes for $k=1,\ldots,7$; the winning candidate is the one who gets the larger number of votes. (This is well-defined, since $\sum_{k=1}^7F_k=33$ is odd.) This is clearly not straight majority rule, since $f(\langle 0,0,0,0,0,1,1\rangle)=1$, and it clearly satisfies the monotonicity and symmetry conditions.

Suppose that $I\subseteq[7]$ is a coalition; clearly we must have $\sum_{k\in I}F_k\ge 17$, so at least one of $6$ and $7$ must belong to $I$. If $7\notin I$, then $5\in I$. Then for any $a=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_7\rangle\in\{0,1\}^7$ such that $a_5\ne a_6$, $f(a)$ depends on $a_7$, so we must have $7\in I$.

Suppose that $6\notin I$, and that $a_k=1-a_7$ for $k\in I\setminus\{7\}$. If $\sum_{k\in I\setminus\{7\}}F_k\ge 9$, then voter $6$ has enough votes to determine the outcome, so If $\sum_{k\in I\setminus\{7\}}F_k\le 8$. But then $\sum_{k\in[7]\setminus I}F_k\ge 12$, and the voters not in $I$ have enough votes to determine the outcome. Thus, $6\in I$.

Suppose that $5\notin I$, and that $a_6\ne a_7$. If $\sum_{k\in[7]\setminus I}F_k\ge 9$, then the voters in $[7]\setminus I$ have enough votes to determine the outcome. Otherwise, $\sum_{k\in[7]\setminus I}F_k\le 8$, so

$$12\le\sum_{k\in I\setminus\{7\}}F_k\le 15\;,$$

and voter $5$ has enough votes to determine the outcome when voter $7$ disagrees with the rest of $I$. Thus, $5\in I$.

It’s straightforward to check in similar fashion that $4\in I$, then that $3\in I$, and finally that $I=[7]$ and hence that $f$ is irreducible.

I’ve not yet really tried to see how much this idea can be generalized — quite a bit, I suspect.

Comment: (+1) A slightly easier way to prove that this $f$ is irreducible: $13+3=16$, so if these two vote against the other five, each of the five can make a difference by switching their vote. On the other hand, $13+3+1=17$, so if these three vote against the other four, each of the three can make a difference by switching their vote. Thus everyone can make a difference.

Comment: @joriki: For some reason it wasn’t immediately obvious to me initially that if every voter can make a difference in at least one situation, then $f$ is irreducible. Na ja, da hatte ich ein Brett vorm Kopf.

Comment: Wow, where did you pick up the nice German? :-) (To your credit, the description of irreducibility in the question somewhat distracts from this simpler characterisation.)

Comment: @joriki: Thanks! I wish it were better, actually: my reading comprehension is decent, if slow — I do read some German fiction for pleasure, not to mention a number of online German news sites — but my production is much poorer, since I rarely have occasion to exercise it.

Comment: Well, you got a number of subtleties right in that one sentence (not to mention the idiom itself) :-)